# Missing My Sites option on my menu in Google Adsense

Tags: adsense

Here are the view of my sidebar in my Adsense account. There should `My sites` option in there but I can't find one.

I haven't registered my website url on Adsense. I am not sure whether this is the reason of getting 403 when my website is getting the advertisement.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @tambre I found many Adsense discussion on Stack Overflow

Comment: Perhaps the answer of this question is the solution of getting 403 when using Google Adsense

Comment: That doesn't mean your question [isn't off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the solution of this problem:

1 . Go to [Adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense).

2 . Sign in to your account or if you have already signed in then skip this step.

3 . Click on My Ads in the menu bar and then click on Other Products.

4 . Enter your site's address and hit enter.

5 . Wait for 2 to 3 days to be approved.

6 . After being approved create an ad unit and copy the ad code and place it into your website or blog where you want to show ads.

Comment: Wow! Amazing.. 2 week or so I struggled until found this! This is gold.

Comment: This should be the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using adsense approved from youtube or admob, thats why there in no website option. Better remove old theme and install new if you're using wordpress. All the best.

Comment: I have both Youtube and admob at the same time. I am not using wordpress but using react to build the web.
Can I also have web advertising when I have Youtube and admob?

Comment: Yes you can but you need to apply for adsense for content and after you can add as many sites as you want. All the best

Comment: I have taken a look to this link: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6023158?hl=en
to see how to apply for adsense for content. However, I can't find the "apply for adsense for content" option in Adsense....